# Irregularity with the looping

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet "result" and  another sheet "status".

The sheet "status" has a table with column A as calendar week.

The idea is to copy the count values of column K, of the "result" sheet to the data sheet.

Similarly other count values in other columns as well.

The code is working fine with no errors.

The problem is I get an error with two of my values. 
CntT acc.to code is providing me with "93" actually , I have "95"
similarly cntS acc to code is providing me "49" while actually I have "50".

Could anyone help me to figure out where I am wrong.I already posted this question and checked with the feedback. It dint work for me.

```
Sub result()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim cntU As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim TotalRows As Long

Set sht = Sheets("Status")
Sheets("Result").Select
TotalRows = Range("E5").End(xlDown).Row
n = Worksheets("Result").Range("E5:E" & TotalRows).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.Count(sht.Columns(1))
    cntT = 0
    cntU = 0
    cntS = 0
    If sht.Range("A" & i) = Val(Format(Now, "WW")) Then Exit For
Next i

For j = 4 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(17))
   If sht.Range("A" & i) = Range("Q" & j) And Range("K" & j) = "Green" Then cntT = cntT + 1
   If sht.Range("A" & i) = Range("Q" & j) And Range("J" & j) = "delayed" Then cntU = cntU + 1
   If sht.Range("A" & i) = Range("Q" & j) And Range("A" & j) = "" Then cntS = cntS + 1
   If cntT <> 0 Then sht.Range("C" & i) = cntT
   If cntU <> 0 Then sht.Range("D" & i) = cntU
   If cntS <> 0 Then sht.Range("B" & i) = cntS
   If n <> 0 Then sht.Range("E" & i) = n
Next j

If cntT + cntU <> 0 Then
    sht.Range("F" & i) = (cntS / n)
    sht.Range("G" & i) = (cntT / n)
    sht.Range("H" & i) = (cntS / n)
    sht.Range("G" & i & ":F" & i & ":H" & i).NumberFormat = "0.%"
End If

'sht.Range("G" & i & ":F" & i & ":H" & i).NumberFormat = "0.%"

End Sub
```

Comment: Debug your code step by step in your `For j ... Next j` loop and verify the Values that your Ranges are passing out.

Comment: `For j = 4 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(17))` <-- this statement looks unusual to me. Are you sure it does what you expect it to do?

Comment: @A.S.HYa, it is doing what I want

Comment: @ A.S.H is there any other way I could declare ?

Comment: I would use instead: `For j = 4 To  Sheets("Result").Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Does the "Green" and "delayed" were manually inputted by users? Any changes in letter case will not be counted on your loop.

Comment: @A.S.H It worked :) thank you so much